# Drop a user that is created with a script in Oracle DB with the (%)

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell

I am trying to drop a user that is created with a sql script that is pass the user with an argument with a PowerShell script each time the script is run. Example: "ZKOracle01", ZKOracle02, and so on.

I was hoping I could get something like this to work at the beginning of the script to clean up the old users.

```
DROP USER LIKE ZKOracle%;
```

I know I could just do this at the beginning or end of my sql script,

```
DROP USER ZKOracle01;
```

but I need the user to remain in the DB for at least 6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a bit of dynamic SQL

```
BEGIN
  FOR u IN (SELECT *
              FROM dba_users
             WHERE username LIKE 'ZKOracle%')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP USER ' || u.username;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I'd probably extend that to add a bit of logging, at least writing out the list of usernames that you're dropping, but that should do what you want.  Remember as well that `DROP USER` is DDL so it implicitly commits before and after the statement-- you cannot rollback your changes.

To show an example of this working (the user I created was not case sensitive)

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  begin
  2    for u in (select * from dba_users where username like 'ZKORACLE%')
  3    loop
  4      execute immediate 'drop user ' || u.username;
  5      dbms_output.put_line( 'Dropped user ' || u.username );
  6    end loop;
  7* end;
SQL> /
Dropped user ZKORACLE01

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to run this.  "Error: ORA-06550: line 6, column 48:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   return returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <>
   and or like like2 like4 likec between into using || bulk
   member submultiset"

Comment: @user3826435 - In my script, line 6 is the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  Is that what's on line 6 in your script?  Is there an EOF character in your script?

Comment: Yes, line 6 is EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on my script. By the EOF character do you mean a semicolon?

Comment: @user3826435 - No, Oracle is complaining about an "end of file" character, not a semicolon.  Can you edit your question to post exactly what you're doing?  That script works fine for me in SQL*Plus.

Comment: The only thing I am currently trying to run is the code above, nothing else. I just wanted to see it works and I get that error. I ran the select statement within it to make sure that it works and it does.

Comment: @user3826435 - You're typing the script above into a SQL*Plus window exactly as written?  If so, I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: @user3826435 - I posted a copy and past example of running the code in SQL*Plus successfully.  Can you do the same illustrating the error?